# JuliaDB select a column from a string, not a symbol

Tags: julia, juliadb

I want to select a column from a JuliDB database. The problem is that I can't do it with string (not a symbol that starts with `:`), for example:

```
db = loadtable("table.dat")
#This table has 3 columns named  position_1, position2, position_3
pos_num = 3
column_name = "position_$pos_num"
select(db,column_name)
```

If I do that, then the following error appears:

```
column position_3 not found.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symbol directly `Symbol("position_$pos_num")` or from your string with `Symbol(column_name)`.